# There is a <p> tag to display text bt I want to break or add <br/> tag in the middle. so how can added th:text in p tag

Tags: thymeleaf

I have

`<p>details<br>subDetails</p>

I want to use th:text in p tag. 
<p th:text="#{context.body.details}">details<br>subDetails</p>`

is it the right way?

Comment: Replace the `#` with `$`?

Comment: Thanks @HaldenCollier
$ it's used to show the dynamic value of the variable
and
# is used to show the static value of the variable (message.properties).

Comment: No worries, it’s hard to spot these things sometimes

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? `th:utext` might help you.

Comment: @want2learn I want simple print the details(in a sentence) by using a 'p' tag where details are got from `th:text` but the condition is that there may be a 'br' tag in the middle. So how can  I get it?

Comment: did you try `th:utext` ?